# Log SQL queries in project using MyBatis and Spring

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, mybatis, ibatis

In my project i have

```
<bean id="ABCSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="ABCDataSource" />
  <property name="mapperLocations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:com/myco/dao/XYZMapper.xml</value>
       </list>
  </property>
<bean>
```

and

```
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=debug, stdout, abclog
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=debug, stdout, abclog
log4j.logger.java.sql=debug, stdout, abclog
log4j.logger.org.mybatis=debug, stdout, abclog
log4j.logger.org.apache.ibatis=debug, stdout, abclog
```

I dont see the SQL queries when i run the applicartion in log
Wanted to know what am i missing

saw this post [how to configure log4j for Mybatis to print my SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267834/how-to-configure-log4j-for-mybatis-to-print-my-sql)
suggesting to change mybatis class configuration but not sure how to do with spring SqlSessionFactoryBean

Answer (score 13):

Quoting from an answer of [how to configure logback for Mybatis to print my SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718097/how-to-configure-logback-for-mybatis-to-print-my-sql), I'm not sure if this will work for you in entirety. It provides the Spring config for logging. This approach worked for me.

> To log SQL statements for particular mybatis mapper set DEBUG (TRACE
>   to see query parameters and results) level for logger with fully
>   qualified mapper name

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.mapper.MyMapper" level="DEBUG"/>
```

> You can log all SQL statements from all mappers if they are in the
>   same package like this

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.mapper" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Give it a go, if the problem is still there. Good luck!

Answer (score 12):

You can add logging for Mybatis via it's mybatis-config.xml.

Add log4j like so:

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <settings>
    ...
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
    ...
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your log4j.properties, add the class that you'd like to log:

```
log4j.logger.org.mybatis.example.MyMapper=TRACE
```

SQL statements are logged at the DEBUG level, so set output to DEBUG:

```
log4j.logger.org.mybatis.example=DEBUG
```

For more details, see the [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html).

Comment: Configuring DEBUG log level will show the query sent + parameters + number of results. Configuring TRACE log level will add the query response columns and values

Answer (score 5):

Another shortcut is to set the debug level of your mybatis mappers to true in your application.properties file:

```
logging.level.<packageName>.mapper=DEBUG
```

Example log printed in console or your log file:

```
2020-03-03 09:41:27.057 DEBUG 10495 --- [io-50006-exec-1] c.f.t.d.m.M.countByExample               : ==>  Preparing: SELECT count(*) FROM MessageRecivers WHERE ((ReciverId = ? and ReadStats = ? and ReciverMessageFolder <> ?)) 
2020-03-03 09:41:27.066 DEBUG 10495 --- [io-50006-exec-1] c.f.t.d.m.M.countByExample               : ==> Parameters: 58(Long), 0(Short), 1(Short)
2020-03-03 09:41:27.473 DEBUG 10495 --- [io-50006-exec-1] c.f.t.d.m.M.countByExample               : <==      Total: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Test with the simplest way configuration and see in the log. Then customize the output (e.g. the files, levels).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" 
                                     "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: where to write the configurations>

Comment: Hi, @eatSleepCode  I can not follow you. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean where to write the configuration, in log4j.xml? Also the thing is I am not able to get the output on console.

Comment: If you are using maven, put this configuration in the file `log4j.xml` in the `src/main/resources` folder. Otherwise, in the default package.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add all the necessary lines to your configuration.

Here is the sample that should work:

```
#configure root logger
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file, stdout

#configure all mybatis mappers logging
log4j.logger.com.myco.dao=ERROR
#configure your mapper logging
log4j.logger.com.myco.dao.XYZMapper=DEBUG

#configure appender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Two way to implement:

1. edit logback.xml:

```
<logger name="mapperPackageName" level="debug"/>
```

2. edit application.properties

```
logging.level.<mapperPackageName>=DEBUG
```

the `mapperPackageName` is the package where the Mapper class is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it by calling `LogFactory.useStdOutLogging();` [java configuration] in the main method or somewhere when the connections factory is created.

[image]

Read more https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html