# how to configure logback for Mybatis to print my SQL

Tags: logback, mybatis

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="java.sql" level="DEBUG" >
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I want print sql and error only,but it does not print SQL in Console,can any one help me? thanks lot

Comment: Hi,In which file should we add the above code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You configuration of appender is correct but logger configuration is not.

To log SQL statements for particular mybatis mapper set DEBUG (TRACE to see query parameters and results) level for logger with fully qualified mapper name

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.mapper.MyMapper" level="DEBUG"/>
```

You can log all SQL statements from all mappers if they are in the same package like this

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.mapper" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Comment: What if my Mappers are in different packages?  Does it mean I have to add a logger for every package?

Comment: If you use mapper XML files likes '<mapper namespace="org.mybatis.example.BlogMapper">', add the namespace as the logger name. <logger name="org.mybatis.example.BlogMapper" level="DEBUG"/>

Answer (score 1):

```
     <logger name="org.mybatis">
      <level value="TRACE"/>
  </logger>

<logger name="java.sql">
    <level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

I used the above code snippet in my logback.xml and got the sql query in logger. If require to print sql in specific logger, use  tag.

Answer (score -1):

thanks, I add to logback.xml

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logFile}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${logFile}.%d.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%date] [%level] %msg [%file:%line] [%logger{100}] [%thread] [AspLink-${project.version}]%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[AspLink-${project.version}] [%level] %msg [%file:%line] [%logger{100}]%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="liquibase" level="INFO" />
<logger name="ru.company.asplink.dao" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.mybatis">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```