# How can I see SQL queries in a SpringBoot+Mybatis Project?

Tags: logging, spring-boot, mybatis

My project is built with Spring boot and Mybatis, I want to see the sql query statements, what can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19623701/5873923

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log SQL queries in project using MyBatis and Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465739/log-sql-queries-in-project-using-mybatis-and-spring)